# What's the better way to reply to the email

Tags: american-english, british-english

> Is this the official email to log on to the website.?

how should I reply to this

what text can I add to YES which would be appropriate

Thanks

Comment: Context, please. That email doesn't make any sense, so it's hard to tell what you could add to your reply.

Comment: I'd answer that the proper reply is "Yup", but that's too short to get past the triviality filter here. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always, the best way to answer a question is using the same words in it. So, the best I can say is:

> Yes, this is the official email to log onto the website. Thanks for
>   asking.